# How to read some element name from XML using GData library?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser, gdata

I am making an app in which I am using SOAP web service, I am receiving this data -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<User xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.myurl.com/">
  <code>200</code>
  <profile>
      <NewDataSet xmlns="">
        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
          <id>1</id>
          <country>Afghanistan</country>
          <isd_code>93</isd_code>
          <timezone>+04:30</timezone>
          <visible>false</visible>
        </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </profile>
</User>
```

And I am using GData library to read this data. I am able to read `<NewDataSet>` element values but don't know how to read value of `<code>` tag. So please suggest me to do this.

Comment: Xml you inserted is invalid. `code` tag is closed two times.

Comment: you can try for some tutorials to learn xml parsing.. raywenderlich has some nice tutorials for this..

Comment: I have changed my XML.